# tasklist.exe gives incorrect errors

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, remote

Running `tasklist.exe` to check the running processes on a remote system. I sometimes get spurious errors (listed below).

Command:

```
tasklist.exe /nh /s \\RemotePcName /fi "memusage gt 200000" 

ERROR:

    Description = The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.


ERROR: The remote system must be running Windows 2000 or above.
```

When I manually check the remote system in question, it lists memory as 17% used (2.8/15.8GB) and it is, in fact, running Windows 10!

What could be going on here?

Comment: Google for some of these terms:
0x5af 1455 ERROR_COMMITMENT_LIMIT - these are the error "codes" for the error message text: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.